# Error:Could not find property 'assembleDebug' on project ':app'

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I am using `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6'` and Android Studio 2.2 Preview 6. The build runs perfectly fine on Gradle 2.1.0, but to enable instant run it asks me to update Gradle plugin.

On updating Gradle plugin, the build shows `"Error:Could not find property 'assembleDebug' on project ':app'"`. I already tried cleaning `.gradle` and `.idea` and reloading the project, but nothing works.

Please help.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

1. find which task is depending on **assembleDebug** task
2. changing the following did the trick for me at least:

from:

```
task findbugs(type: FindBugs, dependsOn: assembleDebug)
```

to:

```
task findbugs(type: FindBugs, dependsOn: "assembleDebug")
```

so just surrounding the task with quotes was enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  been searching for this answer for ages xD

Comment: You're my king ! To find the line, put your project in "Project" mod in Android Studio, right click on the Root folder, find in path, type "assembleDebug". It is in the quality.gradle for me.

Comment: I get an error: **No signature of method: java.lang.String.dependsOn() is applicable for argument types**

Comment: Like a charm, mate. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Thanks! Very useful.

Comment: this solution worked for me, but I don't know what is it doing?
Could somebody please explain it to me?

Answer (score 7):

It's from [In that case, a workaround is this way:](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219732#c21)

```
//assembleDebug.doFirst {
//    println '=============assembleDebug============='
//}
//assembleRelease.doFirst {
//    println '=============assembleRelease============='
//}
//

// =======>

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
        //task.dependsOn 'checkstyle', 'findbugs', 'pmd', 'lint'
        println '=============assembleDebug============='
    } else if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        //task.dependsOn 'checkstyle', 'findbugs', 'pmd', 'lint'
        println '=============assembleRelease============='
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no any "assemble" in your project, so check an answer from this post:

[Could not get unknown property 'assemble'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198154/could-not-get-unknown-property-assemble)