# assembleDebug.dependsOn not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

First of all: This is not a duplicate of this

[Error:Could not find property 'assembleDebug' on project ':app'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38547400/770467)

The problem:

Since the update to Android Studio 2.2 (gradle plugin 2.2) You can no longer make the task `assembleDebug` or `assembleRelease` to be dependent on a new task in this way:

`assembleDebug.dependsOn 'checkstyle'`

More details in this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219732)

It gives you the following error:

> Error:Could not get unknown property 'assembleDebug' for project
>   ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 23):

An alternative is to refer to the task in the following way:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
        task.dependsOn 'checkstyle'
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Android tasks are typically created in the "afterEvaluate" phase. Starting from 2.2, those tasks also include "assembleDebug" and "assembleRelease". To access such tasks, the user will need to use an afterEvaluate closure:

```
    afterEvaluate {
        assembleDebug.dependsOn someTask
 }
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219732#c32

Answer (score 1):

put this inside buildTypes method in build.gradle
for me this code worked :

```
task setEnvRelease << {
            ant.propertyfile(
                    file: "src/main/assets/build.properties") {
                entry(key: "EO_WS_DEPLOY_ADDR", value: "http://PRODUCTION IP")
            }
        }

        task setEnvDebug << {
            ant.propertyfile(
                    file: "src/main/assets/build.properties") {
                entry(key: "EO_WS_DEPLOY_ADDR", value: "http://DEBUG IP TEST")
            }
        }
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
            if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
                task.dependsOn 'setEnvDebug'
            } else if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
                task.dependsOn 'setEnvRelease'
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way that I found to work in gradle version 2.2.0:

in your build.gradle file:

```
task dummyAssembleDebug{
    dependsOn 'assembleDebug'
}
```

and then to use it

```
tasks.dummyAssembleDebug.dependsOn someTask
```