# Could not get unknown property 'assemble'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So, yesterday all was fine but now Android Studio with my project is throwing this error:

```
ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'assemble' for task ':patternjkh:assembleDebug' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

I googled for a long time but haven't found any solution for me.
My project has no any word 'assemble' (ctrl+shift+f in project).

Also I've tried **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart** and **Clean - Rebuild Project**.

Also I've tried to remove project from disk and clone it from bitbucket again. But nothing have helped me at all.

module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 48
    versionName "0.0.48"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

ext {
supportVersion = "28.0.0"
constraintVersion = "1.1.3"
firebaseVersion = "11.6.2"
picassoVersion = "2.5.0"
tinkoffVersion = "1.4.5"
roundedImageView = "2.3.0"
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraintVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$firebaseVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebaseVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$picassoVersion"

implementation "com.makeramen:roundedimageview:$roundedImageView"

implementation "ru.tinkoff.acquiring:ui:$tinkoffVersion"

implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

project's gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradlew clean build --stacktrace:

```
    Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':patternjkh'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:70)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:666)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:135)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:167)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'assemble' for task ':patternjkh:assembleDebug' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:83)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.DefaultTask_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.getAssembleTask(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:88)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:479)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:191)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:78)
        at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin$_addPluginTasksToLibraryVariantsIn_closure4.doCall(CrashlyticsPlugin.groovy:130)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:71)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:160)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$1.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:123)
        at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SingletonSet.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:155)
        at org.gradle.internal.MutableActionSet.execute(MutableActionSet.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:204)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:198)
        at com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.addVariant(LibraryExtension.java:92)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ApiObjectFactory.create(ApiObjectFactory.java:132)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:760)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:746)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:652)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:648)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
        ... 81 more
```

Comment: Can you share you Gradle files both app and project gradles?

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf yeah, I've edited my question

Comment: Take a look at the solutions here: https://github.com/Zomato/AndroidPhotoFilters/issues/12#issuecomment-272371269 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547400/errorcould-not-find-property-assembledebug-on-project-app and tell me if that fixes the issue or not.

Comment: please post the stack trace from `./gradlew clean build --stacktrace`

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf I've told that my project has no any words "assemble"

Comment: @Simon yeah, edited

Comment: Just one more question, have you recently updated Android Studio and/or it's gradle plugin to the newest version? If not, does the problem prevail after the update?

Comment: @Simon no. I've just opened my project at all

Comment: I was able to run my project few minutes ago just after commenting all crashlytics dependencies from app's and project's gradles. Why it could be happened? What should I do now? Just wait?

Comment: It's strange. The same problem appeared in my project too. It worked in the morning, I restarted AndroidStudio 1 hour ago and I started getting the same error. I also have Crashlytics included.

Comment: @EAMax For me it also starts working again after removing Crashlytics from all gradle files. Please keep us updated if you find a solution without removing Crashlytics.

Comment: Just happened to me like 5 minutes ago without doing anything except changing a couple lines of code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1` instead of `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+`

Comment: This is the solution. The Fabric Gradle plugin was updated yesterday to 1.28.0: https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin The new version seems to cause some problems.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank your for a solution and explanation.

Comment: 1.27.1 works as well. I wonder what is the solution going forward, with 1.28.0...

Comment: Looks like this error occurs if you add `apply plugin "io.fabric"` to a library module (with `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`), but it works fine if you apply it to an application module (with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`)

Answer (score 0):

io.fabric keep on changing,Here you can check change-log for fabric

https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin

Try using latest one (as per 15-march-2019) io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0 instead of io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+

for me latest one(io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0) is not worked,
but (io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1) is worked.

Answer (score -1):

"for me latest one(io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0) is not worked, but (io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1) is worked."

Solution: you can change io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0 -> io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0
it works for me.